# t-sql most preferred way with join

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 sql queried below. What is the most preferred method of getting table1.date > 0

Option1:

```
    select table1.id,table2.firstname, table2.lastname
    from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.date > 0
```

Option2:

```
    select table1.id,table2.firstname, table2.lastname
    from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id where table1.date > 0
```

Comment: Before query optimizers you might have seen different performance but I bet both have the same query plan now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the second option easier as it is clearer, and I know that data is being filtered by the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: +1 Agreed... it doesn't make sense to filter out rows from the left side of the join in a subsequent `on` clause...

Answer (score 3):

ALWAYS use the second option.

For an `INNER JOIN` these are equivalent.

**For an `OUTER JOIN` the two versions will return different result sets!**

If you put that filter in your `ON` criteria for an `OUTER JOIN`, you will have records filtered out before the `JOIN` is applied (instead of after) which may give you unexpected results.

Comment: +1 For explaining that they're functionally different when dealing with outer joins...

Comment: Also, if you try to apply a filter to the right side of a `left outer join` in the `where clause`, it will eliminate any `null`s turning it into an `inner join`...

Answer (score 1):

I would take option 2, it is always better to have the join on values and later exclude the ones you don't need in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    table1.id, table2.firstname, table2.lastname 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE table1.date > 0
```

Should work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Not the question but in an outer join and versus where can make a difference.

Consider the following.
The second returns all the rows in docSVsys and first does not. 
The where basically turned the outer join into a regular join.

```
    select COUNT(docSVsys.sID)
    from docSVsys 
    left outer join docMVtext 
    on docMVtext.sID = docSVsys.sID 
    where docMVtext.fieldID = 130

    select COUNT(docSVsys.sID)
    from docSVsys 
    left outer join docMVtext 
    on docMVtext.sID = docSVsys.sID 
    and docMVtext.fieldID = 130
```

I have had some big queries where pulling a condition from the where to the and resulted in the same query but a different query plan.

Answer (score -1):

Option 2 is syntactically correct and it works fine.You are applying the filter correctly using WHERE condition.

Option 1  is correct but it's not easy to distinguish when compared to Option 2.